# CoreData delete save Error

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

```
    [request2 setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate * predicate2 = [ NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"logoFrameNum == %@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:7]];
    [request2 setPredicate:predicate2];    


    NSManagedObject * collectionList2 = [[ managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request2 error:&error2] objectAtIndex:0];


    NSLog(@"context :%@", deleteContext1);
    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:collectionList2];

    BOOL yesorno = [collectionList2 isDeleted];

    NSLog(@"yesorno : %i", yesorno);

    NSError * error10;

    NSLog(@"[managedObjectContext ] : %@", deleteContext1);

    [collectionList2 release];

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error10]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error10, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail

    }
```

There is much more source above it. Change variables or get data from coredata is well performed with the same NSManagedObjectContex I have there. However delete with that context makes me crazy. It crashes without any error message just in

```
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error10]) {
```

I tried get a new context and so on and on........a lot..

Comment: Where does `deleteContext1` come from?

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a `release` on an object (`collectionList2`) that you don't own. This may cause a crash later on (for example, during the save). Try removing the `release`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to delete a `nil` object.
Also, you should do all this within one single `NSManagedObjectContext`.
Try putting your `save:error:` method right below the `deleteObject:` call.